# is top.document cross browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm writing a javascript that relies on top.document but I'm not sure if I can assume all the major browsers supports it or not.

Is top.document cross-browser compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_obj_window.asp), window.top is supported in IE (since v4), FF (v1), and Opera (v9).  I can personally vouch for it working in Safari as I just tried their example code in my own browser.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but I believe it is.

Nested frames are so passe.

Check out this handy [Quirksmode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/frameintro.html) on the topic.

Comment: 6 years later I was curious what the problem is with nested frames (iframes?), but it's a dead llink